# how to call OCL constraints( generated java source code of model ) from the main code of java

Tags: java, eclipse-emf-ecore, ocl

I am using OCL constraints on ecore model and generating code. So the thing is as simple as this
I have a class Task having attribute `startDate` and `endDate`
it has an ocl constraint :- invariant   which states `startDate <  endDate`.

I have generated java code for this project and there is a java class :

```
public class TmsValidator extends EObjectValidator {

  //what is diagnosticChain and context in the below method

  public boolean validateTask_C2(Task task, DiagnosticChain diagnostics, Map<Object, Object context) {
    return validate(TmsPackage.Literals.TASK,
         task,
         diagnostics,
         context,
         "http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore/OCL/Pivot",
         "C2",
         TASK__C2__EEXPRESSION,
         Diagnostic.ERROR,
         DIAGNOSTIC_SOURCE,
         0);    
  }
}
```

So from my main class, how do I validate my task here  . I want to call the OCL
constraint to check if `startDate` is less than `endDate`

```
public class {  
  public static void main(String []a){  
    Task t = new
    Task ();    
    // How do I validate my task here  . I want to call the 
    //OCL constraint to check if startDate is less than endDate         
  }     
}
```

Comment: Just so you know you had formatted the code using quotes (`"`) instead of code (`{ }`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're more likely to get speedy answers using eclipse.modeling.mdt.ocl or eclipse.tools.emf forums.  Of course you using TmsFactory.eINSTANCE to create instances of your model and you can use Diagnostician.INSTANCE to validate all constraints on your modeled objects.